# Regular Expression for day validation on monthly basis

Tags: jquery, regex

I am currently working on validating a form. I have run into a roadblock when it comes to the date. Perhaps some of you crazy RegEx guys could shed some light on the subject. I google'd until I came down with arthritis.

Currently, I am using the following RegEx:

```
var dateReg = /^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- //.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- //.](19|20)\d\d$/;
```

This validates in the mm/dd/yyyy format, but only validates for anything under 31 days. Is it possible to do the day validation on a per-month basis? Would it be recommended to go another route with this?

Comment: Yes, it would be recommended to go another route. A regexp is not well suited to verifying dates. How are you going to account for Feb. 29 being valid once every 3 years?

Comment: @Wooble Don't say that!!! the regex geeks are watching!!!

Comment: Google "javascript date validation". First hit: http://www.smartwebby.com/DHTML/date_validation.asp

Comment: 04/31/2012 validates in your example. Thus, putting me in the same boat I am currently in.

Comment: @Wooble - But Feb 29 is _not_ valid once every 3 years!

Comment: @ridgerunner, 3 = 4 for sufficiently large values of 3? :)

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this (I just pumped it back up one). As Wooble correctly points out, validating using regex is not a good idea, but plucking out the day/mon/year values using regex is perfectly fine and appropriate (and the above regex looks pretty good to me).

Comment: "I google'd until I came down with arthritis. " Then you have at least one thing in common with Vladimir Kramnik, who was chess world champion for 7 years. But to put jokes aside, sp00m is right, his answer is correct, you should validate your date as date and enforce date format with regexp.

Answer (score 1):

As @Wooble explained, a regexp won't be able to suit your needs. What about this:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.isValidDate === "undefined") {
    String.prototype.isValidDate = function() {
        var data = this.split(/[ -./]/);
        var day = parseInt(data[1]);
        var month = parseInt(data[0]) - 1;
        var year = parseInt(data[2]);
        var date = new Date(year, month, day);
        return date.getDate() === day
            && date.getMonth() === month
            && date.getFullYear() === year;
    }
}

document.write("11 02 2011".isValidDate());​
document.write("<br />");
document.write("11 32 2011".isValidDate());
```

Prints:

```
true
false
```

A demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j4WZ5/3/).